# Training Tesseract-OCR with JTessBoxEditor

Tags: ocr

I have problem with this program that we want to download the jTessBoxEditor for training tesseract language file, but when we try to download it ,it downloads ocr program "VietOCR.NET and also how can i download jTessBoxEditor and install it on windows OS ?
can anyone help me ? it is so important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go the page for training...
http://vietocr.sourceforge.net/training.html
Click the link on the first word on the page: jTessBoxEditor
This should bring you to their download site - files are in ZIP format.
The ZIP file contains the jTessBoxEditor and is executed from there.